# Producer side compression in apache kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I hve enabled snappy compression on producer side with a batch size of 64kb, and processing messages of 1 kb each and setting linger time to inf, does this mean till i process 64 messages, producer wont send the messages to kafka out topic...
In other words, will producer send each message to kafka or wait for 64 messages and send them in a single batch...

Cause the offsets are increasing one by one rather than in the multiple of 64

Edit - using flink-kafka connectors

Answer (score 1):

Messages are batched by producer so that the network usage is minimized not to be written "as a batch" into Kafka's commitlog. What you are seeing is correctly done by Kafka as each message needs to be accounted for i.e. identified key / partition relationship, appended to the commitlog and then offset is incremented. Unless the first two steps are done, offset is not incremented.

Also there is data replication to be taken care of based on configurations as well as message tracking systems get updated for each message received (to support lag apis).

Also do note, the batch.size parameter considers ready to ship message's size, which has been pre-processed as 1. compressed 2. serialized by your favorite serializer.

Comment: Atleast in the kafka out topic we should observe the messages to come in batches... But we are not observing this behaviour... We are receiving the messages one by one... EDIT - i am using flinkkafka connectors

Comment: we clearly observe that msgs came all of a sudden as a batch in topic (while observing through console-consumer). Serialization & compression maybe changing data size impacting batch processing. Try adding more messages ~100 or so and send.

Comment: I sent over a 100,000 messages, each message being 1kb in size and batch size being 128kb, still we observed the messages coming one by one when we were using flinkkafka connectors..... While we observed the messages to come in a batch while using native kafka connectors... So is this a bug in flinkkafka connectors?

Comment: Missed to note that you are using Flink-Kafka, flink internally will give records one by one to executors (defined in parallelism). This is an intended behavior, if you define a batch window of e.g. 5 sec, all records will be buffered internally by Flink and will be provided to executors one by one for processing. Not sure what exactly you wanted to observe. I have created a new chat room, pls ping there if need to discuss further https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/178030/apache-kafka